# React project creation files and dependencies

Tags: reactjs

For every React project I create with `npx create-react-app project-name`, is it a necessity to download all the files and dependencies?

Is it possible to make a *common* directory containing all the necessary files and dependencies?

Comment: react and all it depdency are chaning each and every day.